# Fix the value of the description for a link in the "Link or Picture" list field

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, links

On sharepoint 2013 I have a list and one of the field is a Link and picture field, we use this for links only. I would like to set the description to some text e.g. "Click Here" whenever there is a link set in the field e.g. not blank. this should override anything the user may have entered for the description, not the link itself.

This is so we don't have long links showing in the list.

Can this be done in items validation field or else where?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use JSLink to take control of the rendering of your field. It requires development skills, but is still very easy to do. Check out the PnP example for JSLink, https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Branding.JSLink

If this answers your question, please mark as answer.

Comment: thanks but I was hoping for an answer without compiling code...
could it be done within a workflow on the create?

Comment: @Adrian JSLink does not require you to compile code. Just write the js file, upload to SharePoint and register it. Registration can be done with PowerShell if you prefer. You can build a workflow if that is more in your comfort zone. It is still important to mark as answer if it helps you, it will help others in the future.